# angularjs catch validation error in controller thrown by own directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

Hello I want to catch validation error in my controller.

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="col-50">
  <input type="tel" name="phoneNumber" ng-model="appointmentForm.phoneNumber" ng-pattern="/^\+?\d{6,15}$/">
  <div role="alert">
    <span class="error" ng-if="submitted && form.phoneNumber.$error.pattern" >
        Vul een geldige telefoon
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

So how can I catch the error on controller side? I tried to use

```
$scope.form.phoneNumber.$error
```

to get access to the errors but its not working.

Is there a good way to check if the full form has some errors?